# Is it a bad idea to return different data types from a single function in a dynamically typed language?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-typing, static-typing

My primary language is statically typed (Java).  In Java, you have to return a single type from every method.  For example, you can't have a method that conditionally returns a `String` or conditionally returns an `Integer`.  But in JavaScript, for example, this is very possible.

In a statically typed language I get why this is a bad idea.  If every method returned `Object` (the common parent all classes inherit from) then you and the compiler have no idea what you're dealing with.  You'll have to discover all your mistakes at run time.

But in a dynamically typed language, there may not even be a compiler.  In a dynamically typed language, it's not obvious to me why a function that returns multiple types is a bad idea.  My background in static languages makes me avoid writing such functions, but I fear I'm being close minded about a feature that could make my code cleaner in ways I can't see.

---

**Edit**: I'm going to remove my example (until I can think of a better one).  I think it's steering people to reply to a point I am not trying to make.

Comment: Why not throw an exception in the error case?

Comment: @TrueWill I address that in the next sentence.

Comment: Have you noticed that this is a common practice in more dynamic languages? It's common in *functional* languages, but there the rules are made very explicit. And I know that it's common, especially in JavaScript, to allow *arguments* to be different types (as that's essentially the only way to do function overloading), but I've rarely seen this applied to return values. Only example I can think of is PowerShell with its mostly-automatic array wrapping/unwrapping everywhere, and scripting languages are a bit of an exceptional case.

Comment: Not mentioned, but there are many examples (even in Java Generics) of functions that take a return-type as a parameter; e.g. in Common Lisp we have `(coerce var 'string)` yields a `string` or `(concatenate 'string this that the-other-thing)` likewise. I've written things like `ThingLoader.getThingById (Class<extends FindableThing> klass, long id)` as well. And, there, I might only return something that subclasses what you asked for: `loader.getThingById (SubclassA.class, 14)` might return a `SubclassB` that extends `SubclassA` ...

Comment: Dynamically typed languages are like the **Spoon** in the movie *The Matrix*. Do not try to define the **Spoon** as a *string* or a *number*. That would be impossible. Instead... only try to understand the truth. That there is no **Spoon**.

Comment: What is the purpose of "But in a dynamically typed language, there may not even be a compiler."?  I don't see how that's relevant to the question.

Comment: In a "dynamic" language, the concept of "type" is replaced by that of "public API". And if you're returning things with different APIs, then your function is both doing to much and imposing too many responsibilities on its caller. All this is modulo a sensible exception-handling system.

Comment: @Aaronaught I'd be surprised to find function overloading in any dynamically-typed language. Perhaps a matter of perspective but I always thought of func overloading as the kludge for lacking variable length/type args.

Comment: I have had to debug a function like this recently, and it adds to the confusion. Sometimes the function returned a filename, sometimes the opened file handle sometimes the file contents. You can see a variable looking at the code, but it could have one of 3 different types. We should be making things clearer not more ambiguous.

Comment: If you don't understand why returning multiple types is a bad idea, you did not fully understand why typing is a good idea indeed... Enabling the compiler to perform compile time optimizations is but one of the benefits...

Answer (score 43):

By contrast to other answers, there are cases where returning different types is acceptable.

**Example 1**

```
sum(2, 3) → int
sum(2.1, 3.7) → float
```

In some statically typed languages, this involves overloads, so we can consider that there several methods, each one returning the predefined, fixed type. In dynamic languages, this may be the same function, implemented as:

```
var sum = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

Same function, different types of return value.

**Example 2**

Imagine you get a response from an OpenID/OAuth component. Some OpenID/OAuth providers may contain more information, such as the age of the person.

```
var user = authProvider.findCurrent();
// user is now:
// {
//     provider: 'Facebook',
//     name: {
//         firstName: 'Hello',
//         secondName: 'World',
//     },
//     email: 'hello.world@example.com',
//     age: 27
// }
```

Others would have the minimum, would it be an email address or the pseudonym.

```
var user = authProvider.findCurrent();
// user is now:
// {
//     provider: 'Google',
//     email: 'hello.world@example.com'
// }
```

Again, same function, different results.

Here, the benefit of returning different types is especially important in a context where you don't care about types and interfaces, but what objects actually contain. For example, let's imagine a website contains mature language. Then the `findCurrent()` may be used like this:

```
var user = authProvider.findCurrent();
if (user.age || 0 >= 16) {
    // The person can stand mature language.
    allowShowingContent();
} else if (user.age) {
    // OpenID/OAuth gave the age, but the person appears too young to see the content.
    showParentalAdvisoryRequestedMessage();
} else {
    // OpenID/OAuth won't tell the age of the person. Ask the user himself.
    askForAge();
}
```

Refactoring this into code where every provider will have its own function which will return a well-defined, fixed type would not only degrade the code base and cause code duplication, but also will not bring any benefit. One may end up doing horrors like:

```
var age;
if (['Facebook', 'Yahoo', 'Blogger', 'LiveJournal'].contains(user.provider)) {
    age = user.age;
}
```

Comment: _"In statically typed languages, this involves overloads"_

I think you meant "in _some_ statically typed languages" :) Good statically typed languages don't require overloading for something like your `sum` example.

Comment: @AndresF.: thank you, I edited my answer. By curiosity, what are the statically-typed languages which don't require overloads in this context?

Comment: For your specific example, consider Haskell: `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`. You can sum a list of anything that is a number. Unlike javascript, if you attempt to sum something that is not a number, the error will be caught at compile time.

Comment: @MainMa In Scala, `Iterator[A]` has method `def sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B`, which again allows to sum any kind of numbers and is checked at compile time.

Comment: Actually in your first example you are returning objects with the same type: [`Number` (doc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Comment: @Florent: in JavaScript, yes, but other dynamic languages differentiate integers from floats.

Comment: @AndresF. That's more restricted than in most dynamic-languages where you can define the behaviour of `+` with *any* class. For example most languages allow `+` also to concatenate strings. AFAIK in haskell you cannot write a function that either sums a list of integers or concatenates a list of strings. (I'd be interested to find out the opposite...)

Comment: @Bakuriu Of course you can write such a function, though you'd first have to either overload `+` for strings (by implementing `Num`, which is a terrible idea design-wise but legal) or invent a different operator/function that's overloaded by integers and strings respectively. Haskell has ad-hoc polymorphism via type classes. A list containing both integers and strings is much harder (possibly impossible without language extensions) but a rather different matter.

Comment: It seems that it makes sense to return multiple types in one function in all the same places it makes sense to return a generic type in Java.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to articulate it better than this.

Comment: @MainMa In your example 2, are you missing parens or am I ignoring something obvious? `if (user.age || 0 >= 16)`. I would think it should be `if ( (user.age || 0) >= 16)` (assuming Javascript, of course). A minor detail, anyway

Comment: I'm not particularly impressed with your second example. Those two objects are the same conceptual "type", it's just that in some instances certain fields are not defined or populated. You could represent that just fine even in a statically-typed language with `null` values.

Comment: @Aaronaught: what if you don't know in advance what authentication providers will exist in the application, and what would be the possible usages? And wouldn't it be ugly to have an object with *lots* of `null` values (which can easily happen when some providers give a lot of information, while others give just an e-mail address)?

Comment: Seems like a pretty speculative what-if; the whole idea of standards like OAuth is to, well, standardize. As for it being "ugly" to have lots of `null` values - ugly to whom? Obviously in JS it doesn't matter if it's actually `null` or just `undefined`, but unless you're scrutinizing the aesthetics of the JSON over the wire, I can't see a situation in which it would make any practical difference. No matter how you try to spin it, at a fundamental level you're really not returning two different types, you're returning one type that may have several fields either unassigned or undefined.

Comment: @Aaronaught: got it. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to return different types. Your examples as well as the comments by aaronaught and florent already hint to: this can usually be better addressed by redesigning you code and is usually a code smell - a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 33):

In general, it's a bad idea for the same reasons the moral equivalent in a statically typed language is a bad idea: You have no idea which concrete type is returned, so you have no idea what you can do with the result (aside from the few things that can be done with any value). In a static type system, you have compiler-checked annotations of return types and such, but in a dynamic language the same knowledge still exists - it's just informal and stored in brains and documentation rather than in source code.

In many cases, however, there is rhyme and reason to which type is returned and the effect is similar to overloading or parametric polymorphism in static type systems. In other words, the result type *is* predictable, it's just not quite as simple to express.

But note that there may be other reasons a specific function is badly designed: For example, a `sum` function returning false on invalid inputs is a bad idea primarily because that return value is useless and error-prone (0 <-> false confusion).

Comment: My two cents: I hate it when that happens. I've seen JS libraries that return null when there are no results, an Object on one result, and an Array on two or more results. So, instead of just looping through an array, you're forced to determine if it's null, and if it isn't, if it's an array, and if it is, do one thing, otherwise do something else. Especially since, in the normal sense, any sane developer is going to just add the Object to an Array and recycle the program logic from handling an array.

Comment: Counterpoint:  `NaN`

Comment: @Izkata: I don't think `NaN` is "counterpoint" at all. NaN is actually a valid input for any floating-point calculation. You can do anything with `NaN` that you could do with an actual number. True, the end result of said calculation may not be very useful to you, but it won't lead to strange runtime errors and you don't need to check for it *all the time* - you can just check once at the end of a series of calculations. NaN isn't a different *type*, it's just a special *value*, sort of like a [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Comment: @Aaronaught ...Exactly.  Reread delnan's last paragraph.

Comment: @Aaronaught On the other hand, `NaN`, like the null object, tends to hide when errors occur, only for them to pop up later.  For example, your program is likely to blow up if `NaN` slips into a loop conditional.

Comment: @Izkata: NaN and null have totally different behaviours. A null reference will blow up immediately upon access, a NaN propagates. Why the latter happens is obvious, it allows you to write mathematical expressions without having to check the result of every sub-expression. Personally I see null as far more damaging, because NaN is representing a proper numerical concept that you can't get away without and, mathematically, propagating is the correct behavior.

Comment: @Phoshi: In JS, `null` will blow up only when you try to treat it as an object and access its properties.  You can still pass it around, add to it (in which case it acts like zero), cat it onto a string (where it stringifies as `'null'`), etc.

Comment: I don't know why this turned into a "null vs. everything else" argument. I was merely pointing out that the `NaN` value is (a) not actually a different return type and (b) has well-defined floating-point semantics, and therefore really doesn't qualify as an analogue to a variably-typed return value. It's not all that different from *zero* in integer arithmetic, really; if a zero "accidentally" slips into your calculations then you're often likely to end up with either zero as a result or a divide-by-zero error. Are the "infinity" values defined by IEEE floating point also evil?

Comment: @Aaronaught Relevantly, `1/0` appears to result in `Infinity` rather than a divide-by-zero error in Firefox's JavaScript implementation (I haven't tested with other browsers). (Versus Python, where any integer/float combination for `1/0` results in a divide-by-zero error.)

Comment: @cHao: Save the absurd implicit conversion rules, that's how null reacts in most languages. Accessing anything null blows up, just passing it around doesn't, and a lot of the time using it in a string will actually become "null". JS isn't special in its handling there apart from implicitly converting to integers and such.

Answer (score 26):

In dynamic languages, you shouldn't ask whether return *different types* but *objects with different APIs*. As most dynamic languages don't really care about types, but use various versions of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

### When returning different types make sense

For example this method makes sense:

```
def load_file(file): 
    if something: 
       return ['a ', 'list', 'of', 'strings'] 
    return open(file, 'r')
```

Because both file, and a list of strings are (in Python) iterables that return string. Very different types, the same API (unless someone tries to call file methods on a list, but this is different story).

You can conditionally return `list` or `tuple` (`tuple` is an immutable list in python).

Formally even doing:

```
def do_something():
    if ...: 
        return None
    return something_else
```

or:

```
function do_something(){
   if (...) return null; 
   return sth;
}
```

returns different types, as both python `None` and Javascript `null` are types on their own right.

All these use cases would have their counterpart in static languages, function would just return a proper interface.

### When returning objects with different API conditionally is a good idea

As to whether returning different APIs is a good idea, IMO in most cases it doesn't make sense. Only sensible example that comes to mind is something close to [what @MainMa said](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/225693/18392): when your API can provide varying amount of detail it might make sense to return more detail when available.

Comment: Good answer. Worth noting that the Java / statically typed equivalent is to have a function return an interface rather than a specific concrete type, with the interface representing the API / abstraction.

Comment: I think you are nitpicking, in Python a list and a tuple may be of different "types", but they are of the same "duck type", i.e. they support the same set of operations. And cases like this are exactly why duck typing has been introduced. You can do long x = getInt() in Java too.

Comment: “Returning different types” *means* “returning objects with different APIs”. (Some languages make the way the object is constructed a fundamental part of the API, some don't; that's a matter of how expressive the type system is.) In your list/file example, `do_file` returns an iterable of strings either way.

Comment: In that Python example, you could also call `iter()` on both the list and the file to make sure the result can only be used as an iterator in both cases.

Comment: @Gilles lets say that its better to use term "different API", because type can have very language-specific meaning. In javascript it is not the case, I guess.

Comment: @Kaerber - the nitpicking is the edge case, and the edge case is important here. The list and the tuple are both iterable. If your function's job is to return an iterable, then that's great, it returns that one type. But if I think it returns an object with an `append()` method, or `sort()`, etc, there's a big difference between list and tuple.

Comment: returning `None or something` is a killer for performance optimization done by tools like PyPy, Numba, Pyston and others. This is one of the Python-ism that make python not-so-fast.

Answer (score 9):

Your question makes me want to cry a little.  Not for the example usage you provided, but because someone will unwittingly take this approach too far.  It's a short step away from ridiculously unmaintainable code.

The error condition use case kind of makes sense, and the *null pattern* (everything has to be a pattern) in statically typed languages does the same type of thing.  Your function call returns an `object` or it returns `null`.

But it's a short step to saying "I'm going to use this to create a *factory pattern*" and return either `foo` or `bar` or `baz` depending upon the function's mood.  Debugging this will become a nightmare when the caller expects `foo` but was given `bar`.

So I don't think you're being closed minded.  You're being appropriately cautious in how use the language's features.

***Disclosure:*** my background is in statically typed languages, and I have generally worked on larger, diverse teams where the need for maintainable code was fairly high.  So my perspective is probably skewed as well.

Answer (score 6):

Using Generics in Java allows you to return a different type, while still retaining static type safety.  You simply specify the type that you want to return in the generic type parameter of the function call.

Whether you could use a similar approach in Javascript is, of course, an open question.  Since Javascript is a dynamically typed language, returning an `object` seems like the obvious choice.

If you want to know where a dynamic return scenario might work when you are used to working in  statically-typed language, consider looking at the `dynamic` keyword in C#.  Rob Conery was able to successfully [write an Object-Relational Mapper](https://github.com/robconery/massive) in 400 lines of code using the `dynamic` keyword.

Of course, all `dynamic` really does is wrap an `object` variable with some runtime type safety.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bad idea, I think, to return different types conditionally. One of the ways this comes up frequently for me is if the function can return one or more values. If only one value needs to be returned, it may seem reasonable to just return the value, rather than packing it in an Array, to avoid having to unpack it in the calling function. However, this (and most other instances of this) places an obligation on the caller to distinguish between and handle both types. The function will be easier to reason about if it's always returning the same type.

Answer (score 4):

The "bad practice" exists regardless of whether your language is statically typed. The static language does more to steer you away from these practices, and you might find more users who complain about "bad practice" in a static language because it's a more formal language. However, the underlying problems are there in a dynamic language, and you can determine whether they're justified.

Here is the objectionable part of what you propose. If I don't know what type is returned, then I can't use the return value immediately. I have to "discover" something about it.

```
total = sum_of_array([20, 30, 'q', 50])
if (type_of(total) == Boolean) {
  display_error(...)
} else {
  record_number(total)
}
```

Often this kind of switch in code is simply bad practice. It makes the code harder to read. In this example, you see why throwing and catching exception cases is popular. Put another way: *if your function cannot do what it says it does, it should not return successfully*. If I call your function, I want to do this:

```
total = sum_of_array([20, 30, 'q', 50])
display_number(total)
```

Because the first line returns successfully, I assume that `total` actually contains the sum of the array. If it doesn't return successfully, we jump to some other page of my program.

Let's use another example that's not just about propagating errors. Maybe sum_of_array tries to be smart and return a human-readable string in some cases, like "That's my locker combination!" if and only if the array is [11,7,19]. I'm having trouble thinking of a good example. Anyway, the same problem applies. You have to inspect the return value before you can do anything with it:

```
total = sum_of_array([20, 30, 40, 50])
if (type_of(total) == String) {
  write_message(total)
} else {
  record_number(total)
}
```

You might argue that it would be useful for the function to return an integer or a float, e.g.:

```
sum_of_array(20, 30, 40) -> int
sum_of_array(23.45, 45.67, 67.789044) -> float
```

But those results aren't different types, as far as you're concerned. You're going to treat them both as numbers, and that's all you care about. So sum_of_array returns the number type. This is what polymorphism is about.

So there are some practices you might be violating if your function can return multiple types. Knowing them will help you determine if your particular function should return multiple types anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I led you astray with my poor example.  Forget I mentioned it in the first place.  Your first paragraph is on point.  I also like your second example.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it's not very uncommon at all to return different types even in a statically typed language. That's why we have union types, for example.

In fact, methods in Java almost always return one of four types: some kind of object or `null` or an exception or they never return at all.

In many languages, error conditions are modeled as subroutines returning either a result type or an error type. For example, in Scala:

```
def transferMoney(amount: Decimal): Either[String, Decimal]
```

This is a stupid example, of course. The return type means "either return a string or a decimal". By convention, the left type is the error type (in this case, a string with the error message) and the right type is the result type.

This is similar to exceptions, except for the fact that exceptions also are control flow constructs. They are, in fact, equivalent in expressive power to `GOTO`.

Comment: method in Java returning exception sounds weird. "[Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement) an [exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling)"... hmm

Comment: An exception is one possible result of a method in Java. Actually, I forgot a fourth type: `Unit` (a method isn't required to return at all). True, you don't actually use the `return` keyword, but it's a result that comes back from the method nonetheless. With checked exceptions, it is even explicitly mentioned in the type signature.

Comment: I see. Your point seem to have some merits, but the way it's presented doesn't make it look compelling... rather opposite

Comment: In many languages, error conditions are modeled as a subroutine returning either a result type or an error type. Exceptions are a similar idea, except they are also control flow constructs (equal in expressive power to `GOTO`, actually).

Answer (score 4):

No answer has yet mentioned SOLID principles.  In particular, you should follow the Liskov substitution principle, that any class receiving a type other than the expected type can still work with whatever they get, without doing anything to test what type is returned.

So, if you throw some extra properties onto an object, or wrap a returned function with some kind of decorator that still accomplishes what the original function was intended to accomplish, you are good, as long as no code calling your function ever relies on this behavior, in any code path.

Instead of returning a string or an integer, a better example might be it returns a sprinkler system or a cat.  This is fine if all the calling code is going to do is call functionInQuestion.hiss().  Effectively you have an implicit interface that the calling code is expecting, and a dynamically typed language won't force you to make the interface explicit.

Sadly, your co-workers probably will, so you probably have to do the same work anyway in your documentation, except there isn't a universally accepted, terse, machine-analyzable way to do it - as there is when you define an interface in a language that has them.

Answer (score 3):

The one place where I see myself sending different types is for invalid input or "poor mans exceptions" where the "exceptional" condition isn't very exceptional. For example, from my repository of [PHP utility functions](https://github.com/dotancohen/utility-functions) this abridged example:

```
function ensure_fields($consideration)
{
        $args = func_get_args();
        foreach ( $args as $a ) {
                if ( !is_string($a) ) {
                        return NULL;
                }
                if ( !isset($consideration[$a]) || $consideration[$a]=='' ) {
                        return FALSE;
                }
        }

        return TRUE;
}
```

The function nominally returns a BOOLEAN, however it returns NULL on invalid input. Note that **since PHP 5.3, all internal PHP functions behave this way as well**. Additionally, some internal PHP functions return FALSE or INT on nominal input, see:

```
strpos('Hello', 'e');  // Returns INT(1)
strpos('Hello', 'q');  // Returns BOOL(FALSE)
```

Comment: And this is why I hate PHP. Well, one of the reasons, anyway.

Comment: A downvote because someone doesn't like the language that I develop in professionally?!? Wait until they find out that I'm Jewish! :)

Comment: Don't always assume that the people who comment and the people who downvote are the same people.

Comment: I meant it as a joke! Note the :) at the end. In any case, it is likely that whoever upvoted your comment downvoted my answer. I'm not sore, I actually think that it is funny that someone would downvote an answer because they don't like some irrelevant technology mentioned. Rep points are a toy, they come and they go!

Comment: @Aaronaught You do realize that the concept behind this is identical to how you defended `NaN` in another answer, right?  Simple chain of operations, then check at the end?

Comment: I prefer to have an exception instead of `null`, because (a) it [fails loudly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast), so it's more likely to be fixed on development/testing phase, (b) it is easy to handle, because I can catch all rare/unexpected exceptions once for my whole application (in my front controller) and just log it (I usually send emails to dev team), so it can be fixed later. And I actually hate that standard PHP library mostly uses "return null" approach - it really just makes PHP code more error-prone, unless you check everything with `isset()`, which is just too much burden.

Comment: Also, if you return `null` on error, please please please make that clear in a docblock (e.g. `@return boolean|null`), so if I come across your code some day I wouldn't have to check function/method body.

Comment: @scriptin: Of course the return types are fully documented! Actually, looking at the Github page, that particular function hasn't been updated in a while and it doesn't document the NULL return, but most of them do. I'll update the docs. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Developing software is basically an art and a craft of managing complexity. You try to narrow down the system at the points you can afford to, and limit the options at other points. Function's interface is contract which helps to manage complexity of the code by limiting a knowledge required to work with any piece of code. By returning different types you significantly expand the function's interface by adding to it all the interfaces of different types you return AND adding unobvious rules as to which interface is returned.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a bad idea! In contrast to this most common opinion, and as already pointed out by Robert Harvey, Statically typed languages like Java introduced Generics exactly for situations like the one you are asking. Actually Java try to keep (wherever possible) typesafety at compile time, and sometimes Generics avoid code duplication, why? **Because you can write the same method or the same class that handle/return different types**. I'll make just a very brief example to show this idea:

Java 1.4

```
public static Boolean getBoolean(String property){
    return (Boolean) properties.getProperty(property);
}
public static Integer getInt(String property){
    return (Integer) properties.getProperty(property);
}
```

Java 1.5+

```
public static <T> getValue(String property, Class<T> clazz) throws WhateverCheckedException{
    return clazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(properties.getProperty(property));
}
//the call will be
Boolean b = getValue("useProxy",Boolean.class);
Integer b = getValue("proxyPort",Integer.class);
```

In a dynamic typed language, since you have no typesafety at compile time, you are absolutely free to write the same code that works for many types. 
Since even in a statically typed language Generics were introduced to solve this problem, it's clearly a hint that writing a function that returns different types in a dynamic language is not a bad idea.

Comment: Another downvote without explaination! Thanks SE community!

Comment: Have a sympathy +1.  You should try opening your answer with a more clear and direct answer, and refrain from commenting on different answers.  (I'd give you another +1, since I agree with you, but I only have one to give.)

Comment: Generics don't exist in dynamically-typed languages (that I know of). There'd be no reason for them to. *Most* generics are a special case, where the "container" is more interesting than what's in it (which is why some languages, like Java, actually use type erasure). The generic type is actually a type of its own. Generic *methods*, *without* an actual generic type, as in your example here, are almost always just syntax sugar for an assign-and-cast semantic. Not a particularly compelling example of what the question is really asking about.

Comment: "Generics don't exist in dynamically-typed languages" When did I state the opposite? It's **OBVIOUS** that generics don't exist in dynamic languages! My point, I repeat, was: "While that happens to be a necessity (sometimes) in a statically typed language (OMG, that's why Generics exist in Java!) it's a common pattern (to write the same method for many types) in a dynamic language, since you have no typesafety at compile time, you are absolutely free to write the same code that works for many types (Without Generics :-) )."

Comment: I try be a bit more syntetic: "Since even in a statically typed language Generics were introduced to solve this problem, it's clearly a hint that writing a function that returns different types in a dynamic language is not a bad idea." Better now? Check the answer of Robert Harvey or the comment of BRPocock and you'll realize that the example of Generics is related to this question

Comment: The above code won't even compile, since `getValue` doesn't have a return type. Presumably you meant to have it return `T`.

Comment: Don't feel bad, @thermz.  Downvotes often say more about the reader than the writer.

Answer (score 1):

Perl uses this a lot because what a function does depends on its *context*. For instance, a function could return an array if used in list context, or the length of the array if used in a place where a scalar value is expected. From [the tutorial that is the first hit for "perl context"](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=738558), if you do:

```
my @now = localtime();
```

Then @now is an array variable (that's what the @ means), and will contain an array like (40, 51, 20, 9, 0, 109, 5, 8, 0).

If instead you call the function in a way where its result will have to be a scalar, with ($ variables are scalars):

```
my $now = localtime();
```

then it does something completely different: $now will be something like "Fri Jan  9 20:51:40 2009".

Another example I can think of is in implementing REST APIs, where the format of what is returned depends on what the client wants. E.g, HTML, or JSON, or XML. Although technically those are all streams of bytes, the idea is similar.

Comment: You might want to mention the specific way it does this in perl - [wantarray](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html)... and maybe a link to some discussion if its good or bad - [Use of wantarray Considered Harmful at PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=729965)

Comment: By coincidence, I'm dealing with this with a Java Rest API I'm building.  I made it possible for one resource to return either XML or JSON.  The lowest common denominator type in that case is a `String`.  Now people are asking for documentation on the return type.  The java tools can generate it automatically if I return a class, but because I chose `String` I can't generate the documentation automatically.  In hindsight/moral of the story, I wish I returned one type per method.

Comment: Strictly, this amounts to a form of overloading. In other words, there are multiple federated functions, and depending on the particulars of the call, one or the other version is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

In dynamic-land it's all about duck-typing. The most responsible exposed/public-facing thing to do is to wrap potentially different types in a wrapper that gives them the same interface.

```
function ThingyWrapper(thingy){ //a function constructor (class-like thingy)

    //thingy is effectively private and persistent for ThingyWrapper instances

    if(typeof thingy === 'array'){
        this.alertItems = function(){
            thingy.forEach(function(el){ alert(el); });
        }
    }
    else {
        this.alertItems = function(){
            for(var x in thingy){ alert(thingy[x]); }
        }
    }
}

function gimmeThingy(){
    var
        coinToss = Math.round( Math.random() ),//gives me 0 or 1
        arrayThingy = [1,2,3],
        objectThingy = { item1:1, item2:2, item3:3 }
    ;

    //0 dynamically evaluates to false in JS
    return new ThingyWrapper( coinToss ? arrayThingy : objectThingy );
}

gimmeThingy().alertItems(); //should be same every time except order of numbers - maybe
```

It might occasionally make sense to poop out different types altogether with no generic wrapper but honestly in 7ish years of writing JS, it's not something I've found it was reasonable or convenient to do very often. Mostly that's something I'd do in the context of closed environments like an object's interior where things are getting put together. But it's not something I've done often enough that any examples jump to mind.

Mostly, I would advise that you stop thinking about types as much altogether. You deal with types when you need to in a dynamic language. No more. It's the whole point. Don't check the type of every single argument. That's something I would only be tempted to do in an environment where the same method could give inconsistent results in unobvious ways (so definitely don't do something like that). But it's not the type that matters, it's how whatever it is that you give me works.